# C# WPF datagrid - spacing on autowith columns

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, spacing

I have a datagrid with columns. Each column has auto width (depends on the content). My problem is I want a spacing (padding?) between each columns.

I tried to achieve this with the following code:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 0 20 0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

It basically works but if I select a cell, the 20px (padding) does not get selected (its just a design question).

It does not look really pretty. Any ideas?

Comment: IMHO, it 's just normal, this is what I observe on a Datagrid where I don't change the templates: there is some padding that is not selected. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Style to every column and define padding there. Something like `Style="{StaticResource InfoNameTextBlock}"`
And in the class where you keep your style

```
<Style TargetType="yourType" x:Key="InfoNameTextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,0"/>
</Style>
```